# Strange issue in custom timer job - job name is not displayed in job definitions page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs

based on my requirements, I have created a  custom timer job and deployed in the farm. After few days, there is a change in the reqmntmnt, so I modified the code and re-deployed the same.
But the modified timer job name is not appearing in the timer job definitions page.? what may be the  reasons for this ?

I have installed , activated the web appln scoped feature using powershell only.
After this, I have restarted the sptimer  services , multiple times.
still it didn't show up. After this, I have run the iisreset and restarted the server as well. 
Even after doing all the  necessary steps, the timer name is not getting displayed.

when I have tested/newly created a new sptimer soln, that has a simple update of abcd list's title, the timer works.
so,how to identify where is the exact problem?

is there any bug in spdailyschedule class? am using this object.

```
    private bool CreateJob(SPWebApplication site)
       {
          bool jobCreated = false;
          try
           {
              RILTTimer_NPD timerjobrilt = new RILTTimer_NPD(JobName, site);

            SPDailySchedule tempSchedule = new SPDailySchedule();
            tempSchedule.BeginHour = 23;
            tempSchedule.BeginMinute = 5;
            tempSchedule.BeginSecond = 0;
            tempSchedule.EndSecond = 49;
            tempSchedule.EndMinute = 35;
            tempSchedule.EndHour = 24;
            timerjobrilt.Schedule = tempSchedule;
             timerjobrilt.Update();
          }
          catch (Exception)
         {
             return jobCreated;
           }
           return jobCreated;
    }
```

Comment: Debug the timer job and check whether timerjob is created or not by attaching owestimer.exe process.attach the process and activate the  future in central admin for that web application.

Comment: i hav used powershell to activate the feature and ran the nets stop sptimerv and net start sptimerv4 respectively. but still it didnt  work.